# How to code front-end to open quick sign in as popup for saved Username and Password in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, passwords

I have came across few website which gives a native popup for quick login option in chrome browser for already saved username and password. This functionality is very useful for user time saving. However, as an web developer I am not able to find the way of similar implementation for my own projects.

Two popular websites are [www.flipkart.com](https://www.flipkart.com) and [www.aliexpress.com](https://www.aliexpress.com/)

[See this screenshot, where I already have saved two different accounts password in chrome. Now upon first-time opening of the flipkart.com website it automatically opens popup for login.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRKxt.png)

I need help on, what kind of front-end design guideline should be followed to have similar feature in my website as well.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is officially called as a **[Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/)**. In chrome web and mobile browser it may provide quick login account selection popup for already saved username and password in your Google Account.

Though it is a browser feature it is also necessary to have required coding in your website also. In order to do more study on front-end side implementation of Credential Management API, you can refer to **[W3C Tutorial](https://www.w3.org/TR/credential-management/)**